# Topologies on the space of continuous functions on compact sets

Tags: general-topology

I have been trying to find out if the topology induced on $C([0,1])$ by the sup norm coincides with the product topology on $\Pi_{x\in [0,1]} \mathbb{R}$, but neither could prove (or disprove) it by my own nor find it by a web search. I would appreciate if someone gave me some help in this question. Thanks in advance

Comment: The product topology is the topology of pointwise convergence; the topology induced by the sup norm is the topology of uniform convergence. These are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointwise topology on $C([0,1])$ is not first countable. But the sup norm one is even metric (so much more than just first countable). Many more differences exist..

Answer (score 1):

The sup-norm describes uniform convergence of functions, the product topology pointwise convergence. Thus the topologies do not agree.